# No Ash Available--In Need of Aggregates

Tags: construction, materials

Today's concrete, or "Portland cement", has an aggregate (material used to glue everything together) of sand and gravel.

Ancestral, or Roman, concrete, by contrast, had an aggregate of volcanic ash.  Not only does this make the concrete waterproof, it also allows the concrete to harden as it gets older.  This may explain why Roman concrete had endured for two millennia.

But Portland cement has no hope of standing for that long.  Sand and gravel are more porous than ash, which means water and plants can get through, and in a Life After People, it's estimated that they'd stand for only 100-150 years.

In this alternate scenario, ash is in short supply, and the cities are in need of a different kind of aggregate to keep their concrete strong.  Disregarding volcanic ash, sand or gravel, which is the next best material to be used for aggregating the concrete?

Comment: I would suggest anything that can be ground up would work so maybe fired clay would be a good bet.

Comment: I think you are confused. Aggregate is the rocks being glued together by cement to produce concrete. Flyash is vey fine dust and as an additive it made it waterproof. Cement continues to cure with age, it does't have anything to do with the chunks  eing glued together.

Comment: @Bellerephon  I've heard of fired clay being used to build bricks.  But how will they be used to build mortar?

Comment: @JDługosz  An aggregate is actually what keeps something together.  In the case of the Roman concrete, it is volcanic ash.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Construction_aggregate is crushed stone etc. *not* the glue.   I do see surfing wikipedia that ash does act as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pozzolan and that must be what you are referencing. See also [concrete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete) “composed of coarse aggregate bonded together with a fluid cement”.

Comment: The clay can be ground to a coarse powder and used to add strength in a similarity way to gravel.

Comment: @Bellerephon powder and gravel are not the same and don't *add strength* in the same way. You need particles of **all sizes**, the smaller ones filling the gaps left when the larger ones are packed together.

Comment: @JohnWDailey clay in morter: maybe Bellerephon is thinking of how leftover brick bits is added into morter in some cultures.  Note that the difference between morter and concrete is in the sizes of the aggregate.

Comment: Asking for the "best' is usually too opinion-based. And asking for all different possibilities, is too broad. Could you try to provide something to explain how we should judge what is "the best"? Like, durability (like the ashes in your example), price (sand), availability in a given region, etc.

Comment: How is this "off-topic"?

Comment: It isn't off-topic, but it can be seen as too broad.

Answer (score 6):

You're confusing several different effects. Modern [portland cement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portland_cement) is made in a kiln and is essentially a synthetic production of what was found coming from a volcano. But the components are carefully assayed and the process carefully controlled, so it will be *better* than the wild stuff and always consistent in its properties.

What makes surviving Roman concrete particularly good is that besides large rocks, small rocks, sand, etc. as [aggregate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Construction_aggregate), they added *super fine dust* which fills the pores that would form without them. So their souce of volcanic flyash did that without being done on purpose…they just found that it worked.

So are you wanting a [pozzolan](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pozzolan) that is far superior to quicklime in gluing the bits of aggregate together and being weatherproof in comparison to plain calcium hydroxide?  Or do you mean finding the [right mix of aggregate sizes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete#Aggregates) *including ultra-silt* to produce a more waterproof result, so it lasts much longer as water doesn't move through its pores?

To make a super concrete, they would need to figure out both of these issues. Now cement that is immediatly superior to common stuff (portland cement vs plaster of paris in modern terms) is obvious to notice in the short term. Finding additives and *subtle* mixes of aggregate proportions to make the set concrete *harder* is hard to tell without more modern instruments, and longterm wear—how can they *tell* that this recipe will last 100 years vs 20 for harbor footings?

For the better cement, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pozzolan#Pozzolanic_materials) are some natural materials that might work the same.  For the blend of aggregate and filler, anything will do: they just need to find or produce ultra-fine silt and include the right proportions.

The question becomes why would they think to do that or how did they stumble upon it accidently?  One answer might be from the making of fine porcelain where a smooth grain is desired. Look at *bone china* where the minerals are ground and reground to heroic ends. Maybe they got the idea to manipulate the building material in the same way, after seeing that the statues outside the temple stood weather better than the foundation.

---

See also: [The Roman Pantheon: The Triumph of Concrete
Research by David Moore, P.E.](http://www.romanconcrete.com/romanconcrete.htm).  Maybe it will give you some ideas for alternatives, as well as providing more authorative information on just why it was so long lasting.

Comment: Life After People said that modern skyscrapers won't last longer than 150 years because of Portland cement as opposed to the tougher Roman concrete.

Comment: *toughness* has a specific meaning in engineering. The property of interest is water and salt motility.

Answer (score 0):

Why not ash from forest fires or the combustion of other carbon-based biological matter, like people?

One stone which is known to provide exceptional resistance to damage from its use in the walls of certain forts during sieges is Coquina, a sort of sedimentary rock composed of layers of finely crushed ancient seabed biomass (read: ancient clams and stuff), which is extremely absorbent of kinetic impact. One example of this usage is here: https://seashellsbymillhill.com/2014/08/29/castillo-de-san-marcos-history/

Another aggregate usage of this sort of biomass is Tabby concrete, though I have no sources on whether it's particularly good concrete: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabby_concrete

Comment: Because the ash in question are based on silicon or aluminum, not carbon. Nothing to do with common ash as from a fire.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pozzolan#/search

Comment: Sure, but I figured since you CAN make cement out of carbon-based ag, why not mention it? 

Is such cement generally really poor quality?

Comment: I don't know what you are referring to or what is "ag" here.  Black top roads use "carbon based" cement (asphalt),  but that's not the same kind of building material at all.

Comment: Clarify terminology (see links in comments to OP and my answer): **concrete** is hard rocks of all sizes from as large as you can manage for the task down to the finest silt, glued together into a solid mass. In science the rock is a continuous spread serving the same purpose at all scales. In construction work only the coarse rock is called **aggregate**, then sand, then mineral filler.  The stuff that glues it all together is **cement**.

Comment: Re is "tabby concrete any good": shells are the same as limestone only fresher. Burning them makes *quicklime* (calcium oxide), just like limestone or any other source of calcium carbonate. Add water (making *slaked quicklime*, calcium hydroxide), let it absorb carbon dioxide from the air, and you are back to calcium carbonate in the shape you wanted.  That's from memory so pardon any mistakes… you can look it up. I was curious about the history (6000 years!) when I made my smooth plaster ceilings. I used 400 pounds of the stuff, reaching over my head.

Comment: Anyway, using shell for the filler (assuming the new stuff binds well to the shell) just saves energy in reducing the shell to quicklime, and you still get a new block of limestone. It should be the same strength as using all cement, but better in that the set lime is not as optimal as the shell or natural limestone in its crystalline structure and chemical makeup. Adding shells makes it less subject to cracking.

Comment: Ah, they added sand too.  That makes it the same as the morter used for bricks before Portland Cement was invented.

Comment: @JDługosz  Steven S. Ross, author of "Construction Disasters", called volcanic ash "an aggregate".